# Issue with ComposeShader on Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, canvas, gradient, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm just trying to implement a color picker for my android application, and ran into a strange issue on Android 4.1.1. The following code does not create the expected gradients on Android 4.1.1, but it does on 2.3.7:

```
Shader fadeInRight = new LinearGradient(0, 0, pWidth, 0, 0x00000000, 0xFF000000, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
Shader blackToWhite = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, pHeight, 0xFF000000, 0xFFFFFFFF, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
Shader whiteMask = new ComposeShader(blackToWhite, fadeInRight, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
Shader blackToColor = new LinearGradient(0, 0, pWidth, 0, 0xFF000000, hue, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
Shader shader = new ComposeShader(blackToColor, whiteMask, PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN);
paint.setShader(shader);
...
canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, pWidth, pHeight), paint);
```

**Here's the problem:**
[image]

*(ignore the red box below on Android 4.1.1. I just talk about the gradient above)*

**Any Idea what's wrong?** I think there is something missing in my code, but I don't have any idea, what.

**EDIT #1:**
If I just use `whiteMask` for `setShader`, I also get different results for both systems: On the 2.3.7 I can see the text of the configuration menu (which is behind the popup) shining through the gradient rectangle. Furthermore there is a gradient from the upper left edge to the lower right edge (black to white), but the gradient on the 4.1.1 goes horizontally from left to right. **So it seems to be a problem with `ComposeShader`**

**EDIT #2:**
I found a more simpler example to describe the problem:

```
Shader shader1 = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, pHeight, hue, 0xffffffff, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
Shader shader2 = new LinearGradient(0, 0, pWidth, 0, 0xff000000, 0xffffffff, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
Shader shader = new ComposeShader(shader1, shader2, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

So, we have just a vertical linear gradient from any color to black and a horizontal linear gradient from black to white. If we multiply these two layers, we should get the correct rectangle (as in the left screenshot above). But on Android 4.1.1 I see only the gradient of shader2. I also tried this in Gimp with two layers and the result was the same as on Android 2.3.7.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found the problem: Seems that it has to do with the hardware acceleration. As described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) '*`ComposeShader` can only contain shaders of different types (a BitmapShader and a LinearGradient for instance, but not two instances of BitmapShader)*'. But, '*If your application is affected by any of these missing features or limitations, you can turn off hardware acceleration for just the affected portion of your application by calling `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`.*'

I saw, that this method is available since SDK 11. My App supports all versions starting with SDK 7, so I have to check if the method is available:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Now everything's fine.

Comment: Is the hardware acceleration applied by default? I didn't find this information in the link provided by you.

Comment: Not sure, but I think and hope so :-)

Comment: There's also `ViewCompat.setLayerType(view, View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` method / call in support-v4 library.