# Compose two Shaders (Color Picker)

Tags: java, android, shader, android-canvas

In my application I am using my custom color picker widget. In `onDraw` method I mix two `Shaders` using the following code:

```
ComposeShader mShader = new ComposeShader(mValShader, mSatShader, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

However, The result that I get is not what I would like to get.
Below you can see how the `Shaders` mentioned above looks like:
[image] + [image] = [image]

As you can see it totally doesn't works...
This is how result should look like (more or less):
[image]

EDIT (Possible solution):

To make it work I have to use the following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

- [Issue with ComposeShader on Android 4.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445583/issue-with-composeshader-on-android-4-1-1)

However I don't really understand how this line of code affect my application. I mean IU understand it sets the `HARDWARE ACCELERATION`, are there any consequences of doing that for my application? Should I turn it on again after drawing the `Shader`? Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with Android 4+ having Hardware Acceleration(HA) enabled by default. Before 4.0  you could optionaly enable HA in your AndroidManifest.xml .

Hardware acceleration carries out all drawing operations that are performed on a View's canvas using the GPU, which is good because is supposed to be faster. But when HA is enabled some drawing methods are just not supported. So to use the acceleration you can use only a subset of the drawing methods.

In your case the problem is, as the documentation says (see [Unsupported Drawing Operations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported)), that

```
ComposeShader can only contain shaders of different types (a BitmapShader and a  
LinearGradient for instance, but not two instances of BitmapShader)
```

Disabling hardware acceleration.

You can disable HA for your whole application in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

or per activity

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<activity ... />
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
</application>
```

or per view as you are doing now.

Please keep in mind that **there is a bug** in Android that was fixed in 4.1 (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20474&can=1&q=setLayerType%20View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)) and as a result your `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` call will be ignored in some Android versions (4.0.2 for example).

If you disable HA for a view you don't have to enable it back again, since HA affects only the drawing of your view.