# How to set LinearGradients into ComposeShader

Tags: android, gradient

I am trying to make ComposeShader using LinearGradients but may have few problem.
1)  If I am only use one LinearGradient like
**lgA = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, h, 0xff000000, 0xffffffff, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);**
then above part of the requirement correct
2)  If use  ComposeShader then result not like actual requirement

**Actual Requirment :**
[image]

Then how I can solve this problem please any one help me for this problem.

```
public class DrawGradient extends View {

    Paint paint;
    LinearGradient lgA;
    LinearGradient lgB;
    ComposeShader shader;

    public DrawGradient(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        lgA = new LinearGradient(0, 0, w, h, 0xff000000, 0xffffffff, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        lgB = new LinearGradient(0, h, w, 0, 0xffffffff, 0xff000000, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        shader = new ComposeShader(lgA, lgB, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    }
}
```

**Code Output :** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since this four months I imagine this will be of little help now, but here it is for anyone else with a similar problem.

The problem lies in these two lines:

```
lgA = new LinearGradient(0, 0, w, h, 0xff000000, 0xffffffff, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
lgB = new LinearGradient(0, h, w, 0, 0xffffffff, 0xff000000, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

You've created two linear gradients; one going from top-left to bottom-left, the other going from bottom-left to top-right. What you are looking for is this:

```
lgA = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, h/2, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
lgB = new LinearGradient(0, h/2, 0, h, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

With these changes, it worked for me. It's important to note that ComposeShader wouldn't work without the line:

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

For reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445583/issue-with-composeshader-on-android-4-1-1).

ComposeShader seems to be mostly used for overlaying Shaders, such as LinearGradients, rather than creating a three colour transition which you're looking for. Alternatively you could have used LinearGradient by itself, but with the other constructor, which can take more than two different colours. E.g.

```
int[] colors = {Color.BLACK,Color.WHITE,Color.BLACK};
float[] pos = {0.0f,0.5f,1.0f};
paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0,0,0,h,colors,pos,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
```

This would have given you the same effect, without needing ComposeShader. However I was using this method in my own project, but using Color.TRANSPARENT in the gradient and it was coming out black rather than transparent.